# Exception while starting Spark History Server

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have been trying to start Spark History server. I have following settings in `spark-defaults.conf`:

```
spark.eventLog.enabled           true
spark.eventLog.dir              /home/user/Pictures
spark.history.fs.logDirectory   /home/user/Pictures
```

Whenever I run `start-history-server.sh` I get the following exception:

```
20/03/06 12:03:11 INFO history.FsHistoryProvider: History server ui acls disabled; users with admin permissions: ; groups with admin permissions
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer$.main(HistoryServer.scala:296)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer.main(HistoryServer.scala)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Log directory specified does not exist: /home/user/Pictures
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.org$apache$spark$deploy$history$FsHistoryProvider$$startPolling(FsHistoryProvider.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.initialize(FsHistoryProvider.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.<init>(FsHistoryProvider.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.<init>(FsHistoryProvider.scala:86)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /home/user/Pictures
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.org$apache$spark$deploy$history$FsHistoryProvider$$startPolling(FsHistoryProvider.scala:257)
    ... 9 more
```

The directory  `/home/user/Pictures` does exist. It seems that Spark always look for the required directories over HDFS. I have also setup HDFS for Spark standalone mode but currently running my Spark application in `local[]` mode.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]If its local then try prefixing `file:///home/user/Pictures>` in event log and log directory.Hope this helps

Comment: Can you tell why I need to add `file:///`? Previously(before i had setup HDFS), I was just entering it without `file:///` prefix and it was working.

Comment: Well that's the syntax and I can suggest the solution with whatever the info you have provided. That might be the reason,its not able to pick up the location.First test it and then come back if issue persists..